# How do I install the Denodo OData service in the embedded tomcat container in Denodo 5.5?

Tags: tomcat, odata, denodo

I'd like to install the custom OData service into the embedded Tomcat web container in Denodo 5.5.

*I've found that the instructions Denodo provides are somewhat confusing, and thus I'm posting to stackoverflow and including the answer in hopes that someone else finds it useful.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Shutdown Denodo

```
$DENODO_HOME/bin/vqlserver_shutdown.sh
sleep 15
ps -ef | grep denodo | grep -v grep
```

### Obtain the Denodo OData Service.zip

Download the `Denodo OData Service.zip` file and unzip it to `/tmp` such that you have:

```
/tmp/denodo-odata2-service-5.5-20160129
```

### 'Install' the OData Service

```
# copy the war file to the webapps folder
cp /tmp/denodo-odata2-service-5.5-20160129/denodo-odata2-service-5.5.war $DENODO_HOME/resources/apache-tomcat/webapps/

# Copy the odata xml to the embedded tomcat container
cp /tmp/denodo-odata2-service-5.5-20160129/scripts/denodo-odata2-service-5.5.xml $DENODO_HOME/resources/apache-tomcat/conf/DenodoPlatform-5.5/localhost/

# Copy the startup/shutdown scripts to the bin folder
cp /tmp/denodo-odata2-service-5.5-20160129/scripts/*.sh $DENODO_HOME/bin
chmod u+rwx $DENODO_HOME/bin/odata*.sh

# change the DENODO_HOME directory in the $DENODO_HOME/bin/odata*.sh scripts
vi $DENODO_HOME/bin/odata_service_startup.sh   # look for DENODO_HOME and update it
vi $DENODO_HOME/bin/odata_service_shutdown.sh  # look for DENODO_HOME and update it
```

### Make appropriate configuration changes

```
# Add a reference to the Denodo JAR in the catalina.properties file
vi $DENODO_HOME/resources/apache-tomcat/conf/catalina.properties
# Look for shared.loader
# Add this to the end of the shared.loader line:
${catalina.base}/../../lib/vdp-jdbcdriver-core/denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver.jar

# update the server.xml.template file to include a JNDI resource by putting the following in the <GlobalNamingResources> section
vi $DENODO_HOME/resources/apache-tomcat/conf/server.xml.template

<Resource name="jdbc/VDPdatabase"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="admin" password="***********"
    url="jdbc:vdb://localhost:9999/admin"
    driverClassName="com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver"
    initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
    maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
    validationQuery="select * from dual()"
    poolPreparedStatements="true"/>

# Change the permissions on server.xml.template so other people can't read your denodo admin password:
chmod go-rwx $DENODO_HOME/resources/apache-tomcat/conf/server.xml.template
chmod go-rwx $DENODO_HOME/resources/apache-tomcat/conf/server.xml

# update the context.xml to point to the JNDI resource in and also add the properties to the <Context> section (add all of the below to the <Context> section)
vi $DENODO_HOME/resources/apache-tomcat/conf/context.xml

<ResourceLink name="jdbc/VDPdatabase"
    global="jdbc/VDPdatabase"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<Environment type="java.lang.String" name="odataserver.address" value="/denodo-odata.svc"/>
<Environment type="java.lang.Integer" name="server.pageSize" value="1000"/>
<Environment type="java.lang.Boolean" name="enable.adminUser" value="true"/>
```

### Start it up and make sure it works

```
$DENODO_HOME/bin/vqlserver_startup.sh
# wait for Denodo and Tomcat to start

# deploy/start the odata webapp
$DENODO_HOME/bin/odata_service_startup.sh

# Go to 
http://hostname:9090/denodo-odata2-service-5.5/denodo-odata.svc/databasename
(but change "databasename" to your virtual database name)
```

### Additional Considerations

Since you are now using the embedded Tomcat web container and the odata service is running in it, every time you stop/start Denodo you will need to also stop/start the OData service

Stopping Denodo

1. First, stop the OData Service via `$DENODO_HOME/bin/odata_service_shutdown.sh`
2. Then stop Denodo via `$DENODO_HOME/bin/vqlserver_shutdown.sh`

Starting Denodo

1. First, Start Denodo via `$DENODO_HOME/bin/vqlserver_startup.sh`
2. Then, start the OData service via `$DENODO_HOME/bin/odata_service_startup.sh`

Admin User Access

If you don't want the admin user to have access via odata, then change the setting in the `$DENODO_HOME/resources/apache-tomcat/conf/context.xml` file and restart.